# How to run Ionic project with capacitor?

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor

I want to run my Ionic project with capacitor and I have tried different way to  run Ionic project with capacitor even I have created an Ionic blank project using Ionic CLI but I can't do that because of this android studio **error:**

```
  error: resource style/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka com.mahdi.myapp2:style/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
```

This error occurs when I want to build or run my project with android studio. Inside the visual studio code, I don't get an Error

```
Ionic version: 5.4.13
Node version: v10.15.3
Npm version: 6.4.1
```

Thanks for your help

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json

Comment: @MohanGopi I share the file for you

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the libraries installed in your android studio, and nothing to do with ionic settings..
Try steps in this [link](https://github.com/red5pro/streaming-android/issues/31#issuecomment-403013177)